# Dark menu item on dark menu background

Tags: unity, 14.04, menu, ambiance, menu-bar

I recently decided to go back to Ubuntu's default "Ambiance" theme in Unity, but doing so resulted in dark text on dark menus (like the one in the attachment), which I find hard to read! This only happens with menus in the menu bar; my context menus are fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: This just happened to me. It seems to be some sort of a side effect of installing other desktops -- I installed kubuntu-desktop lubuntu-desktop and xubuntu-desktop to experiment with them and saw this on my first login back to Unity. I'm adding this as a comment because I don't have a solution yet. In my experience, it's not so easy to remove desktop environments once they've been installed, so ultimately I'll probably reinstall Ubuntu when I'm through testing.

Comment: I'm noticing that there seems to be something messed up with all the Unity themes -- either the fonts or the color or the font size are all wrong. I just switched to the Radiance theme because it's the least bad one for now.

Comment: To leave some "breadcrumbs" here's what I've tried (though neither worked): (1) reinstalled the light-themes package containing the Ambiance and Radiance themes. (2) recreated the font cache using "fc-cache -rv" ... I logged out and back in afterwards. If either helped at all I couldn't see the difference.

Comment: Here's another clue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/593081/unity-default-settings ... When I did this I found the theme TEMPORARILY looked right. HOWEVER I opened a terminal and ran the command unity-tweak-tool --restart-unity  as mentioned there, and the command never finished. I finally killed it off and couldn't operate Unity, so I opened a VT and rebooted -- to see that the themes are funky again. I just tried to run unity-tweak-tool --restart-unity from a VT, and it doesn't work.