# Unity default settings

Tags: desktop-environments

Every time I boot in to Ubuntu 14.04.02 64 Bit.I have to run `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` to reset `unity` to  its Defaults. This has happened after I install `kubuntu-desktop` and logged in
 to `GNOME` session once?Meanwhile I've removed and reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Now if I login to `Ubuntu` session nothing loads?so I can only log in to `GNOME Flash Back compiz` session..

Comment: Could you add which version of Ubuntu you are using to your queston

Comment: @damien Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `/etc/xdg/autostart/unity-reset.desktop` file, either as `root` (login with `sudo -i`) or simply do `sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/unity-reset.desktop` and put the following information there

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=unity-reset
Categories=Application
Exec=sh -c 'yes "yes" | unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity'

Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

This way you don't have to run unity reset every time, but it will do it for you

Comment: it is not working created file as `root`

Comment: OK. 755 permissions meant it should have been available for all users including root, but apparently it doesn't work that way. As for creating a file as root, using sudo to open a text editor is sufficient to have whatever file you write with text editor , to be owned by root and have -rw-r--r-- permissions

Comment: OK. 755 permissions meant it should have been available for all users including root, but apparently it doesn't work that way. As for creating a file as root, using sudo to open a text editor is sufficient to have whatever file you write with text editor , to be owned by root and have -rw-r--r--

Comment: It can't be run as executable at system start up because `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` asks for options Yes/No while executing

Comment: @Fabby `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity < yes` it does not work and gives `error output`.`bash: yes: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sorry: `yes | unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`

Comment: `yes | unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` also not works

Comment: Yes outputs "y", and for unity tweak tool you actually need to type full string "yes", anything else to exit. It has an option to output a string that you specify. I've edited the code, so try that

Comment: @Serg it gives error after executing`compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
WARN  2015-03-13 12:27:25 unityo (appinfo2) <unknown>:0 g_settings_set_value: value for key 'visual-bell-type' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences' is outside of valid range
ERROR 2015-03-13 12:27:25 unity.shell.compiz unityshell.cpp:2773 Decoration plugin is active, disabling it...`

Comment: @MuditKapil It gives error for the decoration plugin. Did that affect in any way the way program windows look ? It also says the error because that plug in was active and it disabled it. Doesn't sound like anything serious

Comment: @Serg `sh -c yes "yes" | unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity'
 command goes in to a loop