# No Unity Interface after logon

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

I logged onto my computer this morning after having left it off over the weekend and the Unity interface didn't load. I get my desktop and the files I have on it, but no launcher, no menu bar. I tried following [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) but the compiz config manager isn't avaliable through apt-get anymore.

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and it is a fairly recent install of it.

Any help with this would be much appreciated .

Comment: If You have `unity-tweak-tool` installed then from terminal or`tty1`run `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`

Comment: I don't have that unfortunately and apt-get can't find it. Do I need to add a repo?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` then`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` from terminal

Comment: Ok it found it now, but still no unity.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/593081/unity-default-settings if it could help you

Comment: I found that the suggestion from the answer worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/290376/25008

Answer (score 2):

Execute this command in terminal, if you are unable to use terminal , goto tty1 by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login with your username and password , then execute following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop --purge && rm -rf .config .gnome .gnome2 .compiz .cache && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: It says  `E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop`